# get device data from braintree payment gateway

Tags: android, braintree

I need to get device data from  braintree payment gateway for android. But there are some cases in my app where I need to get it without going to Drop-In Ui of braintree.
So I just want to know that is it possible and if yes then how.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact our [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/) team.</sub>

Use our process for [custom device data collection](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/advanced-fraud-tools/client-side/android/v2#custom). This will allow you to collect device data without initiating Drop-in.

Comment: I did the same thing but i am getting null pointer exception on line `return PayPalOneTouchCore.getClientMetadataId(context);` as context is null

Comment: This is a bug in our implementation. You can wait until the fragment has been attached to the activity, then the context will not be null. We will release a fix in the next version of the library.